# What is the use of the %n format specifier in C?

Tags: c, printf, format-string

What is the use of the `%n` format specifier in C? Could anyone explain with an example?

Comment: What has become of the fine art of reading the fine manual?

Comment: I think the real question is what is the **POINT** of the an option like this? why would anyone want to know the value of the numbers of char printed much less write that value directly to memory. It was like the developers were bored and decided to introduce a bug into the kernal

Comment: That's why Bionic let go of it.

Comment: It is in fact a valid question, and one that the fine manuals will likely not answer; it has been discovered that `%n` makes `printf` accidentally Turing-complete and you can e.g. implement Brainfuck in it, see https://github.com/HexHive/printbf and http://www.oilshell.org/blog/2019/02/07.html#appendix-a-minor-sublanguages

Comment: The use of it: crimes

Answer (score 165, accepted):

Nothing printed. The argument must be a pointer to a signed int, where the number of characters written so far is stored.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int val;

  printf("blah %n blah\n", &val);

  printf("val = %d\n", val);

  return 0;

}
```

The previous code prints:

```
blah  blah
val = 5
```

Comment: You mention that the argument must be a pointer to a signed int, then you used an unsigned int in your example (probably just a typo).

Comment: So far I know, type of `int` is implementation-independent. Shouldn't be `signed int` instead of since it might be `unsigned`?

Comment: @AndrewS: Because the function will modify the value of the variable.

Comment: @Jack `int` is always signed.

Comment: @jamesdlin: My mistake. I'm sorry.. I didn't know where I read that.

Comment: @Jack Perhaps you confused it with `char`, where `char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned char` are all separate.

Comment: For some reason the sample raises error with note `n format specifies disabled`. What's the reason?

Comment: @Johnny_D See some of the other answers. `%n` is disabled on some platforms (notably Windows) for security reasons.

Comment: When I try your code it gives me : blah val = 36 ,,,, why 36 ?! I use a 32Bit GCC in a Windows machine

Comment: When compiling with gcc 8.3, this example prints `blah val = 0` (on *one* line).

Answer (score 238):

Most of these answers explain what `%n` *does* (which is to print nothing and to write the number of characters printed thus far to an `int` variable), but so far no one has really given an example of what *use* it has.  Here is one:

```
int n;
printf("%s: %nFoo\n", "hello", &n);
printf("%*sBar\n", n, "");
```

will print:

```
hello: Foo
       Bar
```

with Foo and Bar aligned. (It's trivial to do that without using `%n` for this particular example, and in general one always could break up that first `printf` call:

```
int n = printf("%s: ", "hello");
printf("Foo\n");
printf("%*sBar\n", n, "");
```

Whether the slightly added convenience is worth using something esoteric like `%n` (and possibly introducing errors) is open to debate.)

Comment: Oh my - this is a character-based version of computing the pixel size of string in a given font!

Comment: Could you explain why &n and *s are needed. Are they both pointers?

Comment: @AndrewS `&n` is a pointer (`&` is the address-of operator); a pointer is necessary because C is pass-by-value, and without a pointer, `printf` could not modify the value of `n`.  The `%*s` usage in the `printf` format string prints a `%s` specifier (in this case the empty string `""`) using a *field width* of `n` characters.  An explanation of basic `printf` principles is basically outside the scope of this question (and answer); I'd recommend reading the `printf` documentation or asking your own separate question on SO.

Comment: Great answer, Just one thing James. Why is the asterisk in the string formatter %*s.

Comment: @AndrewS Because that's how the `printf` syntax was designed.  Basically the `*` in `%*s` means to use one of the arguments as a field width.  Please read the `printf` documentation.

Comment: @AndrewS "*integer value or * that specifies minimum field width. The result is padded with space characters (by default)... In the case when * is used, the width is specified by an additional argument of type int.*" from "http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf"

Comment: Why there's a need to use the ampersand and why does it convert the result from the format specifier to an integer?

Comment: @kuhaku The ampersand is necessary because it's an *output* parameter, so you need to pass a pointer to `printf`.  It's the same reason [why you must pass pointers to functions such as `scanf`](http://www.c-faq.com/stdio/scanf1.html).

Comment: Thanks for showing a use-case. I don't understand why people just basically copy-paste the manual into SO and reword it sometimes. We're humans and everything is done for a *reason* which should always be explained in an answer. "Does nothing" is like saying "The word cool means cool" - almost useless knowledge.

Comment: Seems like this could be made more useful if the format string allowed specifying pointers to sizes where as width/precision specifiers. Then you could just make one `printf` call.

Comment: @PSkocik It's convoluted and error-prone enough without adding an extra level of indirection.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I think I've decided that my implementation _is_ going to have it.

Answer (score 21):

I haven't really seen many practical real world uses of the `%n` specifier, but I remember that it was used in oldschool printf vulnerabilities with a [format string attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format_string_attack) quite a while back.

Something that went like this

```
void authorizeUser( char * username, char * password){

    ...code here setting authorized to false...
    printf(username);

    if ( authorized ) {
         giveControl(username);
    }
}
```

where a malicious user could take advantage of the username parameter getting passed into printf as the format string and use a combination of `%d`, `%c` or w/e to go through the call stack and then modify the variable authorized to a true value.

Yeah it's an esoteric use, but always useful to know when writing a daemon to avoid security holes? :D

Comment: There are more reasons than `%n` to avoid using an unchecked input string as a `printf` format string.

Answer (score 16):

The other day I found myself in a situation where `%n` would nicely solve my problem.  Unlike [my earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3402415/179715), in this case, I cannot devise a good alternative.

I have a GUI control that displays some specified text.  This control can display part of that text in bold (or in italics, or underlined, etc.), and I can specify which part by specifying starting and ending character indices.

In my case, I am generating the text to the control with `snprintf`, and I'd like one of the substitutions to be made bold.  Finding the starting and ending indices to this substitution is non-trivial because:

- The string contains multiple substitutions, and one of the substitutions is arbitrary, user-specified text.  This means that doing a textual search for the substitution I care about is potentially ambiguous.
- The format string might be localized, and it might use the `$` POSIX extension for positional format specifiers.  Therefore searching the original format string for the format specifiers themselves is non-trivial.
- The localization aspect also means that I cannot easily break up the format string into multiple calls to `snprintf`.

Therefore the most straightforward way to find the indices around a particular substitution would be to do:

```
char buf[256];
int start;
int end;

snprintf(buf, sizeof buf,
         "blah blah %s %f yada yada %n%s%n yakety yak",
         someUserSpecifiedString,
         someFloat,
         &start, boldString, &end);
control->set_text(buf);
control->set_bold(start, end);
```

Comment: I'll give you +1 for the use case. But you are going to fail an audit, so you should probably devise another way to mark the begin and end of the bold text. It seems like three `snprintf` while checking return values will work just fine since `snprintf` returns the number of characters written. Maybe something like: `int begin = snprintf(..., "blah blah %s %f yada yada", ...);` and `int end = snprintf(..., "%s", ...);` and then the tail: `snprintf(..., "blah blah");`.

Comment: @jww The problem with multiple `snprintf` calls is that the substitutions might be rearranged in other locales, so they cannot be broken up like that.

Comment: Thanks for the example. But couldn't you, like, write an terminal control sequence to make the output bold right before the field and then write a sequence after it? If you don't hardcode the terminal control sequences, you could make them positional (reorderable) too.

Comment: @PSkocik *If* you're outputting to a terminal.  If you're working with, say, a Win32 rich-edit control, that won't help unless you want to go back and parse the terminal control sequences afterward.  That also assumes that you want to honor terminal control sequences in the rest of the substituted text; if you don't, then you'd have to filter or escape those.  I'm not saying it's impossible to do without `%n`; I'm claiming that using `%n` is more straightforward than alternatives.

Answer (score 15):

So far all the answers are about that `%n` does, but not why anyone would want it in the first place. I find it's somewhat useful with `sprintf`/`snprintf`, when you might need to later break up or modify the resulting string, since the value stored is an array index into the resulting string. This application is a lot more useful, however, with `sscanf`, especially since functions in the `scanf` family don't return the number of chars processed but the number of fields.

Another really hackish use is getting a pseudo-log10 for free at the same time while printing a number as part of another operation.

Comment: +1 for mentioning uses for `%n`, although I beg to differ about "all the answers...". =P

Comment: The bad guys thank you for your use of printf/%n, sprintf, and sscanf ;)

Comment: @noloader: How so? *Use of* `%n` has absolutely zero danger of vulnerability to an attacker. The misplaced infamy of `%n` really belongs on the stupid practice of passing a message string rather than a format string as the format argument. This situation of course never arises when `%n` is actually part of an intentional format string being used.

Comment: %n allows you to write to memory. I think you are assuming that the attacker does not control that pointer (I could be wrong). If the attacker controls the pointer (it just another parameter to printf), he/she could perform a write of 4 bytes. Whether he/she can profit is a different story.

Comment: @noloader: That's true about any use of pointers. Nobody says "bad guys thank you" for writing `*p = f();`. Why should `%n`, which is just another way of writing a result to the object pointed to by a pointer, be considered "dangerous", rather than considering the pointer itself dangerous?

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE what will happen if the format string contains "%n" and no other arguments are passed into "printf"?  for instance, printf ("blah%n") ? Is 4 written somewhere?

Comment: @mangusta: Then it has undefined behavior because there's no `int *` argument matching the `%n`.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE it is undefined, but technically doesn't it try to store 4 into the address referred by 1st argument (which wasn't passed and hence is random) on the user stack?

Answer (score 14):

From [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/printf.html) we see that it stores the number of characters printed so far.

> `n`   The argument shall be a pointer to an integer into which is written the number of bytes written to the output so far by this call to one of the `fprintf()` functions. No argument is converted.

An example usage would be:

```
int n_chars = 0;
printf("Hello, World%n", &n_chars);
```

`n_chars` would then have a value of `12`.

Answer (score 13):

The argument associated with the `%n` will be treated as an `int*` and is filled with the number of total characters printed at that point in the `printf`.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't print anything.  It is used to figure out how many characters got printed before `%n` appeared in the format string, and output that to the provided int:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int resultOfNSpecifier = 0;
    _set_printf_count_output(1); /* Required in visual studio */
    printf("Some format string%n\n", &resultOfNSpecifier);
    printf("Count of chars before the %%n: %d\n", resultOfNSpecifier);
    return 0;
}
```

<sub>([Documentation for `_set_printf_count_output`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175782.aspx))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

It will store value of number of characters printed so far in that `printf()` function.

Example:

```
int a;
printf("Hello World %n \n", &a);
printf("Characters printed so far = %d",a);
```

The output of this program will be

```
Hello World
Characters printed so far = 12
```

Comment: when I try you code it gives me : Hello World Characters printed so far = 36 ,,,,, why 36 ?! I use a 32bit GCC in a windows machine.

Answer (score 1):

Those who want to use %n Format Specifier may want to look at this:

***Do Not Use the `"%n"` Format String Specifier***

> In C, use of the "%n" format specification in printf() and sprintf()
> type functions can change memory values. Inappropriate
> design/implementation of these formats can lead to a vulnerability
> generated by changes in memory content. Many format vulnerabilities,
> particularly those with specifiers other than "%n", lead to
> traditional failures such as segmentation fault. The "%n" specifier
> has generated more damaging vulnerabilities. The "%n" vulnerabilities
> may have secondary impacts, since they can also be a significant
> consumer of computing and networking resources because large
> guantities of data may have to be transferred to generate the desired
> pointer value for the exploit. Avoid using the `"%n"` format
> specifier. Use other means to accomplish your purpose.

Source: [link](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:kSJ4iHsKeakJ:https://us-cert.cisa.gov/bsi/articles/knowledge/coding-practices/do-not-use-n-format-string-specifier)

Comment: A real-world example https://github.com/Hamled/mazda-format-string-bug#readme

Comment: Thanks for that real world example mx0, using user input as the format string is stupid, not really an example of where %n in the format string is the problem. Always output user input with printf("%s", user_input)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, %n in 1st argument of print function simply record the number of character it prints on the screen before it reach the the %n format code including white spaces and new line character.`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    printf("%d %f\n%n", 100, 123.23, &i);
    printf("%d'th characters printed on the screen before '%%n'", i);
}
```

output:
100 123.230000

15'th characters printed on the screen before '%n'(with new character).

### We can assign the of i in an another way...

As we know the argument of print function:-

```
int printf(char *control-string, ...);
```

So, it returns the number the number of characters output. We can assign that return value to i.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    i = printf("%d %f\n", 100, 123.23);
    printf("%d'th characters printed on the screen.", i);
}
```

Answer (score -6):

%n is C99, works not with VC++.

Comment: `%n` existed in C89.  It doesn't work with MSVC because Microsoft disabled it by default for security concerns; you must call `_set_printf_count_output` first to enable it. (See Merlyn Morgan-Graham's answer.)

Comment: No, C89 defines not this feature/backdoorbug. See K&R+ANSI-C
http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Language-2nd-Brian-Kernighan/dp/0131103628
??where is the URL-tagger for comments??

Comment: You're simply wrong.  It's listed plainly in Table B-1 (`printf` conversions) of Appendix B of K&R, 2nd edition. (Page 244 of my copy.) Or see section 7.9.6.1 (page 134) of the ISO C90 specification.

Comment: Android also removed the %n specifier.

Comment: [Documentation for `_set_printf_count_output`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175782.aspx)