# in C, what is "%n" ? and how does this code work?

Tags: c, format, scanf

In c programming language, what's the placeholder "%n" ??
and how the following code works ?

```
    char s[150];
    gets(s);
    int read, cur = 0,x;
    while(sscanf(s+cur, "%d%n", &x, &read) == 1)
    {
        cur+= read;
        /// do sth with x
    }
```

-- This code gets a line as character array and then it scan the numbers from this character array,
ex : if `*s="12 34 567"`
the first time `x = 12`
next time `x = 34`
at last `x = 567`

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401156/what-is-the-use-of-n-format-specifier-in-c#answer-3401176

Comment: Somebody should publish a standard or specification or manual or book that explains things like this. It is a shame none can be found anywhere on the planet.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I hope you're being sarcastic.

Comment: I would discourage the use of `gets`, as the C11 standard does by *deprecating* it. It introduces the problem of buffer overflow. You could fix this error by using `fgets`, instead. Additionally, neglecting the return value of *any standard C function* might lead to undefined behaviour. Perhaps you could search for "opengroup fgets" in order to find a manual, skip to the "RETURN VALUE" section and write code to ensure the return value is as expected before the logic continues. You might save yourself a whole lot of crying and time wasting!

Answer (score 5):

from the man page

```
n      Nothing is expected; instead, the number of characters  consumed
              thus  far  from  the  input  is stored through the next pointer,
              which must be a pointer to  int.   This  is  not  a  conversion,
              although  it can be suppressed with the * assignment-suppression
              character.  The C standard says: "Execution of  a  %n  directive
              does  not increment the assignment count returned at the comple‐
              tion of execution" but the Corrigendum seems to contradict this.
              Probably it is wise not to make any assumptions on the effect of
              %n conversions on the return value.
```

Comment: The corrigendums contradiction is erroneous. The latest standard is best to go by, in which the erroneous example from the corrigendum is corrected and included.

Answer (score 0):

Here, `"%n"` represents the number of characters read so far.

Answer (score 0):

`%n` stores the number of characters of the input string which have already been processed into the related parameter; in this case `read` would get this value.  I rewrote your code a bit to dump what happens to each variable as the code executes:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
  {
  char *s = "12 34 567";
  int read=-1, cur = 0, x = -1, call=1;

  printf("Before first call, s='%s'  cur=%d   x=%d   read=%d\n", s, cur, x, read);

  while(sscanf(s+cur, "%d%n", &x, &read) == 1)
    {
    cur += read;

    printf("After call %d, s='%s'  cur=%d   x=%d   read=%d\n", call, s, cur, x, read);

    call += 1;
    }
  }
```

which produces the following

```
Before first call, s='12 34 567'  cur=0   x=-1   read=-1
After call 1,      s='12 34 567'  cur=2   x=12   read=2
After call 2,      s='12 34 567'  cur=5   x=34   read=3
After call 3,      s='12 34 567'  cur=9   x=567  read=4
```

Share and enjoy.