# Why does C have the %n format specifier, despite the obvious downsides?

Tags: c

I've been learning about format string vulnerabilities, and it's the first time I've ever heard of `%n`. And I don't understand why it exists.

Okay, sure, I can imagine cases where you'd like to know how many characters you've written so far. But there are a lot of other ways to find the length of a string, and `%n` seems like a bizarre approach. It's unlike all the other format specifiers, because it doesn't write to the string, it writes to some other manually-specified location in memory. And because it's so unintuitive - who would expect printf to write to arbitrary memory? - it seems to have an obvious potential for creating security holes. Unless someone warns you about format string vulnerabilities, you might never think about it.

There must have been a reason for doing things this way. But what was it? Or were the problems described above just not considered to be serious at the time?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401156/what-is-the-use-of-n-format-specifier-in-c

Comment: Worst wording for a question EVER. If you had simply asked "what's a valid use for..." you might have gotten an answer.

Comment: I already know how it works. I want to know why the language was designed this way, instead of just letting people use strlen().

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I don't quite understand what you're saying. My question is: Why was the %n format specifier defined in the C language, despite its obvious downsides? Maybe I should change my title to reflect that.

Comment: It's hazardous only if the format string can be modified at run time; if it's a literal, you simply pass the address of an `int` object corresponding to the `"%n"` specifier. As for `strlen`, if you're writing to a file using `printf` or `fprintf`, there's nothing to apply `strlen` to.

Answer (score 2):

As show in [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401156/what-is-the-use-of-n-format-specifier-in-c) It doesn't actually store it's value in random memory.

---

> Nothing printed. The argument must be a pointer to a signed int, where the number of characters written so far is stored.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int val;

  printf("blah %n blah\n", &val);

  printf("val = %d\n", val);

  return 0;

}
```

---

This argument is useful if you want to know when to wrap lines on consoles, want to align your values and for other formatting processes you may wish to do to your output.

Comment: I understand that it's not stored in "random memory", and I get that this is how it works. But I'm wondering why it works this way. Is it more convenient when calculating line wraps, compared to, say, strlen()?

Comment: Unless you always print your output to a string buffer using `sprintf` or equivilent and then `strlen` before using `printf` there is no other way (without being hacky) to get the length of the `printf` output.

Comment: Except `\t` is treated as one character, which means you can't use it for correct line wrapping either.

Comment: @Mehrdad Don't use `\t` then, I never have in any of my outputs and i'm not even avoiding it.

Comment: @Serdalis: Patient: "Doctor, doctor! It hurts when I walk!" Doctor: "Don't walk then :P, I have a wheelchair and I'm not even avoiding walking"

Comment: @Mehrdad Ah ok, I'll delete my comment I did find it funny was just unsure if it was serious.