# C: Expalanation for %No as a format specifier for printf

Tags: c, printf, mingw

The output of the following piece of code (considering `%No` as a string),

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    // your code goes here
    printf("%No");
    return 0;
}
```

on a linux machine is: `%No`

while on a windows machine is: `13`

For the following code (considering `%No` as a format specifier), output

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    // your code goes here
    printf(" %c %No %d",65,65,23);
    return 0;
}
```

on a linux machine is: `A %No 23`

while on a windows machine is: `A 101 23`

The output on the windows machine keeps on varying with different arguments for `%No` specifier. Any explanation about this specifier would be very helpful.
Thanks in Advance.

---

output of `gcc -v` on my windows machine

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/program files (x86)/codeblocks/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.7.1/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: mingw32
Configured with: ../../src/gcc-4.7.1/configure --build=mingw32 --enable-languages=c,c++,ada,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --enable-threads=win32 --enable-libgo
mp --enable-lto --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-gnu-ld --disable-nls --disable-wi
n32-registry --disable-symvers --disable-build-poststage1-with-cxx --disable-werror --prefix=/mingw32tdm --with-local-prefix=/mingw32tdm --enable-cxx-
flags='-fno-function-sections -fno-data-sections' --with-pkgversion=tdm-1 --enable-sjlj-exceptions --with-bugurl=http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/bugs
Thread model: win32
gcc version 4.7.1 (tdm-1)
```

---

**EDIT**:

Got my answer, as cremno pointed out, `%N` does nothing, and `%o` prints in octal, so in `%No` , `N` is ignored and `%o` is used to print the passed argument as octal. The remaining question is why passing no argument is taken as `11`(in decimal). FYI in ASCII `11` represents a vertical tab.

Comment: The answer provided is correct, you have mismatched `printf` format/arguments and Windows/Linux handle "undefined behaviour" very differently. As an aside, here's a link about what the `%n` `printf` format specifier does and how it's useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401156/what-is-the-use-of-the-n-format-specifier-in-c ..

Comment: @txtechhelp My question is, what does `%No` specifier stands for in windows? And I have corrected the mismatched `printf` format/arguments.

Answer (score 4):

You have mismatched printf format string and arguments; that results in undefined behaviour. Anything could happen. If you want to print a literal `%`, use `%%` in the format string.

Comment: In that case, what does `N` stand for?

Comment: That depends on the particular C libraries being linked against, I guess.  As far as I know that's not *anything* for glibc, which is probably why linux just prints it as a string without any conversions.

Comment: A quick search of the microsoft docs for Visual Studio 6 didn't turn anything up either. I guess it's just the behaviour when encountering unknown formats that's different.

Comment: `N` is a length modifier in MSVCRT. It stands for `near`. `F` is for `far`. They do nothing nowadays, but in 16-bit x86 days they could've been used with `%s` or `%p`.

Comment: @cremno: Do you have any link to docs still remembering that (not purged by MS)? Or did you just remember that from ancient times?

Comment: @Rufflewind: Seen what cremno said? Anyway, it need not detect that, though as a matter of QoI it should do something sensible, like crashing, upon encountering an invalid specifier. Or at least asserting that in debug mode.

Comment: @Deduplicator: [From Visual C++ 1.52c (MSCXX.HLP)](https://i.imgur.com/uxhxWtS.png).

Comment: @cremno: wow that's good to know; I'm surprised they removed any mention of it in the official docs!

Comment: @cremno Please note that the modifier in question is `%No` not `%N`.

Comment: @Nishant: Your terminology is wrong. `N` is the length modifier (MS-specific) and `o` the conversion specifier (Standard C). Also, `%No` makes no sense.