# What does conversion specifier %n exactly do?

Tags: c, printf

I just encountered this by looking in the standard:

> 7.19.6.1 The fprintf function

in

> 8 The conversion specifiers and their meanings are:

regarding to:

> n     The argument shall be a pointer to signed integer into which is written the
> number of characters written to the output stream so far by this call to
> fprintf. No argument is converted, but one is consumed. If the conversion
> specification includes any flags, a field width, or a precision, the behavior is
> undefined.

What does this mean? What does %n do?

Did I get it correct, that acording to:

> Returns
>
> 14 The fprintf function returns the number of characters transmitted

In this snippet:

```
int a, b;
b = printf ("Thi%n\s is just a test",&a);
```

`a` would equal to `b`?

Comment: What happens when  you try it? Is `a == b`?

Comment: `a` will be `3` because 3 characters have been written thus far (`Thi`). The  value of `b` is unrelated to `%n`.

Comment: Not on a machine where I'm able to test, just have my printed c99 with me to fight boredom ;p

Comment: Related to [What is the use of the %n format specifier in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3401156/1708801)

Comment: In your example, `n` would be equal to 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the number of characters written to the output stream so far

"So far", means wherever you place your `%n`, the result will change. As of your example, it will be 3.

If your increase your `%s` position by one char, the resulting variable pointed will increase by one. Placing your `%s` at the very end of the string will make it equal to the value returned by `printf`

Comment: I probably just wasn't able to really get the "so far" because of my incapabillity to see a relevance in it. Well to know, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

a = 3 and b = 19 for your case

a will be equal to number of character printed before %n.
Suppose you try to print printf ("This%sis%n just a test","coder", &a);
Then the value of a will be this + coder + is = 11.

And the value of b is always the total number of characters printed