# %n format specifier program giving different outputs on different compilers. Why?

Tags: c++, c, printf

I was reading about `%n` format specifier in C at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401156/what-is-the-use-of-the-n-format-specifier-in-c). But when I tried the following program on different C++ compilers, it gave me different outputs.

Why? What is the reason? Is there undefined or implementation defined behavior occurring?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int c = -1;
  printf("geeks for %ngeeks ", &c);
  printf("%d", c);
  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

#### Code blocks 13.12: (correct output)

```
geeks for geeks 10
```

#### Borland/CodeGear/Embarcadero C++: (correct output)

```
geeks for geeks 10
```

#### Orwell Dev C++:

```
geeks -1
```

#### Microsoft Visual Studio 2010:

```
Debug assertion failed ("'n' format specifier disabled",0)
```

Comment: Because the exact implementation is left over being compiler specific?

Comment: _"Orwell Dev C++"_ Boils down to some MinGW GCC version, correct?

Comment: You should initialize `c` to something like 0 so you can tell if it was touched or not.  34 might be the uninitialized value.

Comment: You may want to initialize `c` with some value, say, `-1`, and try the experiment with `Orwell Dev C++` again. See if you get `-1` back (in which case you would know that `%n` is not supported).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: yes, i got -1 back as output in Orwell Dev C++.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: It looks like there is a mingw option and a gcc option for Orwell Dev C++. From the context clues, I would guess that it is using mingw.

Comment: @BillLynch How do they differ exactly?

Comment: @BillLynch: Hmm. MinGW uses gcc as its compiler, so I'm not sure having a mingw option vs. a gcc option makes sense, but it probably would with more context. But the use of gcc shouldn't be relevant; `printf` is part of the C runtime library, not the compiler. MinGW uses gcc as its compiler and the Microsoft runtime library (which dislikes `%n`).

Comment: Some of the answers at that other question already address why Microsoft disabled `%n`.

Comment: @jamesdlin, that's pretty weak justification for intentionally being non-conforming.  Since an essential requirement for a program to be open to a format string exploit is that it uses user-controlled data as a format string, a far better solution would be to warn about variable format strings, as some other compilers do.  I can think of only unflattering reasons why MS would approach the problem as it did.

Comment: FWIW, the Borland/Embarcadero C++ compiler also supports `%n` and outputs the correct value.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I'm just the messenger.  That said, I do think that Microsoft took a practical approach: variable format strings are much more common than using `%n`.  Furthermore, *compile-time* warnings are useless for existing binaries, whereas disabling `%n` at runtime would address (albeit potentially break) programs that dynamically linked to the CRT.

Comment: @KeithThompson although MinGW and gcc have the same compiler, they have different standard library implementations. minGW defers `printf` to MSVCRTxxx.dll by default, whereas Linux/gcc uses glibc.  IDK what "orwell dev-c++" does.

Comment: @meet CodeBlocks is an IDE. You can use any compiler with it. I'd suggest changing your post to include the compiler name and version instead.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: gcc itself has no standard library; implementations  combine the gcc compiler with some library. Supposedly Orwell Dev C++ has a MinGW option and a gcc option. Since MinGW uses gcc, that didn't make much sense.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As noted in the question `Code Blocks` is indeed correct while `Orwell Dev C++` is incorrect. Visual Studio on the other hand is non-conforming.

cppreferences [C documentation for printf says](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) says:

> returns the number of characters written so far by this call to the function.

I don't see anything in the draft standard that makes this optional, C++ refers to the C standard with respect to `printf`. [MSDN documents this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf4y5e3w) and says:

> Because the %n format is inherently insecure, it is disabled by default. If %n is encountered in a format string, the invalid parameter handler is invoked, as described in Parameter Validation. To enable %n support, see _set_printf_count_output.

**Why is the %n format is inherently insecure?**

I am assuming that they consider it unsafe because of security issues such as those outlined in [Format String Vulnerability](http://www.cis.syr.edu/~wedu/Teaching/cis643/LectureNotes_New/Format_String.pdf) documents one possible way to exploit this. It is predicated on the format string being controlled by user input. The paper gives the following example:

```
char user_input[100];
scanf("%s", user_input); 
printf(user_input);
```

Retired Ninja linked to [Bugtraq post](http://seclists.org/bugtraq/1999/Sep/328) which demonstrates an real example of such a bug ending up in an exploit in `proftpd 1.2.0pre6`:

> - ftp to host
> - login (anonymous or no)
>
> (this should be all on one line, no spaces)
>
> ftp> ls aaaXXXX%u%u%u%u%u%u%u%u%u%u%u%u%u%u%u%u%u%u%u%u%u%u%u%u%u%u%u
>   %u%u%u%u%u%u%u%u%u%653300u%n
>
> (replace the X's with the characters with ascii values
>   0xdc,0x4f,0x07,0x08 consecutively)
>
> Lots of other nasties can easily be easily done with this.  Since
>   proftpd will pass on user input data to snprintf, argument attacks are
>   easy.

The problem with Visual Studios approach is that it breaks portability. Other approaches include using flags like [Wformat-security used by gcc](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Format-Security-FAQ) which combined with `-WError` can make it an error but you can choose this as part of your build process.

Comment: Why it is inherently insecure? What about other compilers like code blocks, dev C++, clang etc? How they handles this?

Comment: @meet MS views it as  inherently insecure.  That does not mean it is inherently insecure, just that at least one significant vendor thinks so.

Comment: @chux: It also means that Microsoft's implementation is non-conforming by default (which is not news).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncontrolled_format_string  It has been used for exploits in the past.  http://seclists.org/bugtraq/1999/Sep/328

Comment: @Keith Thompson Should MS be consider a leader in this for disallowing `"%n"`by default, yet allowing with a certain compiler switch?  Or is this [Embrace, extend, extinguish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embrace,_extend_and_extinguish)?  Hmmmm

Comment: @chux: It's not even a compiler switch. Apparently you have to *call* `_set_printf_count_output(1)` before calling `printf`.

Comment: @chux the problem is that this breaks portability.

Comment: @RetiredNinja that bugtraq post is an excellent example, thanks

Comment: GCC/glibc and `_FORTIFY_SOURCE > 1` are a bit smarter (can actually be said about fortification vs. Secure CRT (at least in plain C) in general): `%n` is only enabled for read-only format strings (like in the example).

Comment: So don't user unchecked user input as a `printf` format string.

Answer (score 4):

The Code Blocks output is correct.

The Orwell Dev C++ output is incorrect. Either that implementation is not non-conforming by default (read the documentation to see if there's a way to make it behave correctly), or it has a bug.

Microsoft's implementation is non-conforming by default. It disables the standard `%n` format specifier to prevent some possible security problems (though there are no such problems in the code in your question). Apparently there are ways to re-enable it; see [Shafik Yaghmour's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29218954/827263).

The only potential problem I see with your program is that it doesn't print a newline at the end of its output, but that's not relevant to the `%n` issue.