# How does %n work with variables

Tags: c, printf

So I have looked around and I have found little information on %n in general and no info on how to use it with a variable.

As far as I can tell the code I am using should work but I do not know what it is not. The particular line that I am having trouble with is:

```
printf("%d %n", num[x], &c);
```

Below is the entire code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
        //seed rand, declare arrays, declare variables
        srand(time(NULL));
        int num[10];
        int c = 0;
        int total = 0;
        int x;

    printf( "%s%14s%20s\n", "Value", "Characters", "Total Characters" );

    //Loads the num array with random numbers.
    for(x = 1; x  < 10; x++)
    {
            num[x] = 1 + rand() % 1000;
    }

    for (x = 1; x < 10; x++)
    {
            printf("%d %n", num[x], &c);
            printf("%14d", c);
            total = total + c;
            printf("%20d\n", total);
    }
}
```

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401156/what-is-the-use-of-the-n-format-specifier-in-c)

Comment: Little information? Here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf4y5e3w.aspx

Comment: btw : doing calculations of _any_ kind on the output of rand() will _reduce_  its randomness statistically, you are effectively generating pseudo-random numbers which are _more_ predictable.

Comment: @specializt Surely "calculations of any kind on the output of rand() will reduce its randomness" overstates your otherwise valid concern.  Example: `num[x] = rand() ^ 12345;` would not do so.

Comment: using XOR on the output will reduce its randomness - you just narrowed the possible values to a smaller set. Its a common beginners' mistake and the very reason for cryptographic systems being broken at some point. If you want randomness to any degree you need to get a source which creates your desired range. Its that simple. Either that or keep collecting data until something is in your range - which will also reduce randomness but at least the point in time at which the values arrive is unpredictable, thats at least SOME bargain

Answer (score 2):

From the C Standard

> n The argument shall be a pointer to signed integer into which is
>   written the number of characters written to the output stream so far
>   by this call to fprintf. No argument is converted, but one is
>   consumed. If the conversion specification includes any flags, a field
>   width, or a precision, the behavior is undefined.

The same is valid for `printf`

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int n1, n2;

    printf( "%s%n%s%n\n", "Hello", &n1, " World", &n2 );

    printf( "%d\t%d\n", n1, n2 );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Hello World
5   11
```

Comment: I read this but I am still having trouble. I don't know if I am using improper syntax or if I missed something. As far as I can tell, from all of the examples I have found, I am doing it correctly but my output is reading as if nothing was stored into the variable.

Comment: @s.lucas See my updated post that includes now an example.