# Use of %n more than once in a format string does not seem to work

Tags: c

I am trying to make sure I understand how %n is used, and I have the very simple code below

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void)
{
  int c1, c2;
  printf("This%n is fun%n\n", &c1, &c2);
}
```

It should print "This is fun" and store the number of characters printed in c1 and c2. But all I get as an output is the string "This". I am using MinGw v 4.9.3 to compile this on Windows10.

Comment: Perhaps taking a look at [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401156/what-is-the-use-of-the-n-format-specifier-in-c) may cast some light (-:

Comment: Have you tried using `_set_printf_count_output(1);` to enable the use of %n?

Comment: @YotamSalmon: That would not be standard compliant! Not the first MS-detour, don't use MSVC!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program is crashing after printing `This`.

MinGW uses Microsoft's Visual C++ runtime by default. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf4y5e3w.aspx) says following about "%n":

> Because the `%n` format is inherently insecure, it is disabled by
>   default. If `%n` is encountered in a format string, the invalid
>   parameter handler is invoked, as described in [Parameter Validation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ksazx244.aspx). To
>   enable `%n` support, see [`_set_printf_count_output`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175782.aspx).

The default invalid parameter handler aborts your program. Either enable via [`_set_printf_count_output(1)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175782.aspx) or compile with `-D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=1` to use it.

Comment: This behavior by Microsoft's runtime violates the C and C++ standards.

Comment: @KeithThompson: that's seldom worried Microsoft before — why should it worry about it now?

Comment: @KeithThompson: So that makes number - 4711, 10454? :-(( Simple solution: don't use MSVC and the MS-libc.

Comment: @Olaf: Or pay attention to its limitations and be aware of the workarounds. (One workaround is to avoid `%n`; it's rarely all that useful.)

Comment: @KeithThompson: No! MSVC lacks other useful standard features in the language like VLAs, FAMs. There is just no use in using a compiler which has not really been updated since >17 years. It is time to move forward. See the C++ community which already greatly adopted C++11/14. It is ridiculuous to stick with a 27 year old version if there are now 2 updates with the first making great advances. No wonder C looses reputation.

Comment: @Olaf:  I don't happen to use it myself, and I do wish Microsoft kept up with the C standard, but meanwhile people  manage to do useful work with it.

Comment: @KeithThompson: They just should use modern compilers. Sorry, But I'm tired of the problems MSVC raises and the restrictions it imposes for portable projects. Not that they are the only one; they are just the biggest and don't support modern C for business-political reasons (they want to enforce using C# or C++). It would be much easier if they just don't claim they have a C compiler at all.