# Format string %n of printf function doesn't work

Tags: c, security, gcc, format-string, crlf-vulnerability

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int a=100;
    printf("aaaaa%n",&a);
    printf("%d",a);
}
```

I used gcc to compile it ( :gcc a.c )
however, its output is as follows

```
aaaaa100
```

The value of `a` doesn't change by the `printf`'s `%n` format string 
I suppose it should output as follows

```
aaaaa5
```

What is the reason of this unexpected difference? Thank you

Comment: are you sure it prints `aaaaa100` ?

Comment: Are you sure? I get the expected output.

Comment: I get the o/p  aaaaa5. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401156/what-is-the-use-of-the-n-format-specifier-in-c

Comment: what is the version of your gcc? maybe something about the version,,my version is 4.8

Comment: I am sure it output aaaaa100, I don't know what is the reason.@artm

Comment: OK， I solve the problem. It's the matter of gcc's version, I use 5.4 ,perform normal, but 4.8 perform not normal without any warnning.