# C strtok parse complex string

Tags: c, string, strtok

Hello I have a complex problem in C. I want to split this string (with this example I include all trap possibilities)

```
 "command1";"sleep 30; command2 -a ; command3";"command4="MyTest""
```

to :

```
command1
sleep 30; command2 -a ; command3
command4="MyTest"
```

the string is "tab", and elements are separate by double quote and `;`
How can i use `strtok()` for this?

I try to use `strtok()` with ";" separator like this :

```
   char mystring[1024]="\"command1\";\"sleep 30; command2 -a ; command3\";\"command4=\"MyTest\"\"";
   token = strtok(mystring, "\";\"");

   while( token != NULL ) {
      error(token);
      token = strtok(NULL, s);
   }
```

but I have this output :

```
command1
"sleep 30
command2 -a
command3"
"command4="MyTest""
```

Thanks for advance for your help

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine

Comment: @wildplasser does it mean *write an algo* ?

Comment: I would use regular expression to extract the differents parts

Comment: @Cid Yes. It will probably be easier than splitting on `;` +recognising the `"` and requoting the third field.

Comment: `strtok` is not the right tool for this job.  `strtok` does simpleminded splitting at delimiters.  It has no facility for quoting.

Comment: The delimiter string you hand to `strtok` is a *set* of single-character delimiters.  It is not a multi-character delimiter string.  When you call `strtok` with a delimiter string of `"\";\""`, you're saying that tokens are delimited by either `"` or `;`.

Comment: Doing this well is surprisingly tricky.  You can't just search for the explicit delimiter string `"\";\""`, because the input might contain whitespace around the `;`.  Also the input might not contain quotes around commands that don't need it.  Also for full generality you need to figure out a way to allow actual quotes inside a quoted string.

Comment: _"the string is "tab", and elements are separate by double quote and ;"_ This is not true. A _command_ begins with `"` (quote) AND ends with with `";` (quote followed by semicolon) OR `"EOF` (quote and EOF). Just write a simple parser.

Comment: `  "command1";"sleep 30; command2 -a ; command3";"command4="MyTest""` begins with a space.  Is this intended.  Is this important?

Comment: @Cid, Unclear about using "regular expression" in C code.  Are you referring to `*scanf()` functions or some other part of C?  Or maybe some extension to standard C?

Comment: @chux I'm not referring to any specific functions or extensions but a potential way to achieve that goal, hence I commented rather than answered

Answer (score 0):

The example below parses the input string as requested. It will need some adjustments to entirely fit your needs (replace `printf` with your actual processing code).

To understand the code, start from the top comment where the syntax of your string is described. then go to `main` - use a debugger.

Some explanations:

- `iss_t` is an input string stream simulacrum. It is used by `iss_get_char` to read characters from the input string.
- `wschar_t` is used to store a character read from input stream together with previous white spaces. This is necessary because you did not specify if there may be spaces between `"` and `;`. It is used by `iss_get_wschar` and `iss_peek_wschar`.
- `iss_get_wschar` reads white spaces until it finds a non-ws character.
- `iss_peek_wschar`is the same as above except it does not extract the characters from the stream.
- `token_t` describes the tokens a stream is made of.
- `parser_get_token` extracts a token from the stream. It is, perharps, the most important function.
- `parser_commands` extracts all commands from stream and it is the main function of the parser.
- `parser_command` extracts a command from stream.

You can test the code [here](https://ideone.com/5uGGQp).

```
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <ctype.h>

  /*
  commands:
    EOF
    |
    command commands

  command:
    command_begin string command_end

  string:
    anything but command_end

  command_begin:
    QUOTE

  command_end:
    QUOTE SEMICOLON
    |
    QUOTE EOF
  */

  struct iss_t
  {
    char* s;
    char* g;
  };
  typedef struct iss_t iss_t;

  char iss_get_char( iss_t* self )
  {
    if ( !*self->g )
      return 0;
    return *self->g++;
  }

  struct wschar_t
  {
    char c;
    char s[ 1024 ];
  };
  typedef struct wschar_t wschar_t;

  char iss_get_wschar( iss_t* self, wschar_t* r )
  {
    char* p = r->s;

    while ( isspace( *p++ = r->c = iss_get_char( self ) ) )
      ;
    *p = 0;
    return r->c;
  }

  char iss_peek_wschar( iss_t* self )
  {
    char* savedg = self->g;
    wschar_t t;
    iss_get_wschar( self, &t );
    self->g = savedg;
    return t.c;
  }

  enum token_t
  {
    tk_done,
    tk_beg,
    tk_end,
    tk_rest
  };
  typedef enum token_t token_t;

  struct parser_t
  {
    iss_t* iss;
    wschar_t wschar;
    token_t token;
  };
  typedef struct parser_t parser_t;

  token_t parser_get_token( parser_t* self )
  {
    iss_get_wschar( self->iss, &self->wschar );

    // if done
    if ( self->wschar.c == 0 )
      return self->token = tk_done;

    // not a quote
    if ( self->wschar.c != '\"' )
      return self->token = tk_rest;

    // it is quote: check the next token
    switch ( iss_peek_wschar( self->iss ) )
    {
    case 0:
    case ';':
      iss_get_wschar( self->iss, &self->wschar ); // eat
      return self->token = tk_end;
    default:
      return self->token = tk_beg;
    }
  }

  int parser_command( parser_t* self )
  {
    printf( "COMMAND: " );
    if ( self->token != tk_beg )
    {
      printf( "command begin expected" );
      return -1;
    }

    while ( parser_get_token( self ) == tk_rest || self->token == tk_beg )
      printf( self->wschar.s );

    if ( self->token != tk_end )
    {
      printf( "command end expected" );
      return -1;
    }

    printf( "\n" );

    return 0;
  }

  void parser_commands( parser_t* self )
  {
    while ( 1 )
    {
      switch ( parser_get_token( self ) )
      {

      case tk_done:
        return;

      default:
        if ( parser_command( self ) < 0 )
          return;

      };
    };
  }


  int main()
  {
    char* s = "\"command1\"; \"sleep 30; command2 -a ; command3\"; \"command4=\"MyTest\"\"";

    iss_t iss = { s, s };
    parser_t parser = { &iss };
    parser_commands( &parser );

    return 0;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

You must be having the string as

```
char str[]="\"command1\";\"sleep 30; command2 -a ; command3\";\"command4=\"MyTest\"\"";
```

You needn't use `strtok()` could use `sscanf()` like

```
char a[3][100];
sscanf(str, "\"%99[^\"]\";\"%99[^\"]\";\"%99s", a[0], a[1], a[2]);
a[2][strlen(a[2])-1]='\0';
printf("\n%s\n%s\n%s", a[0], a[1], a[2]);
```

The last `a[2]` would have an extra `"` at the end this way. We remove it with `a[2][strlen(a[2])-1]='\0';`.

`\"%[^\"]\"` means read a `"`, read everything till before another `"` (this part is stored in a character array) and read that `"` as well.

Width specifiers are used in `sscanf()` to prevent buffer overflow.

You should check if `sscanf()` was successful by checking its return value like

```
if( sscanf(........) != 3)
{
    printf("\nSomething went wrong.");
}
```

`sscanf()` returns the number of successful assignments, which in this case must be `3`.

Output is:

```
command1
sleep 30; command2 -a ; command3
command4="MyTest"
```

Edit:

The array size 100 was arbitrary. If more precise memory allocation is needed you could use dynamic memory allocation first. Like

```
sscanf(str, "\"%*[^\"]%n\";\"%*[^\"]%n\";\"%*s%n", &size[0], &size[1], &size[2]);
printf("\n%d, %d, %d", size[0], size[1], size[2]);
size[2] = size[2]-size[1]-4;
size[1] = size[1]-4;
size[0] = size[0]-1;
char *p[3];
for(int i=0; i<3; ++i)
{
    if( (p[i]=malloc(sizeof(char)*size[i]))==NULL )
    {
        perror("Memory allocation failed!");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

The `%n` format specifier returns the number of characters that are read. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401156/what-is-the-use-of-the-n-format-specifier-in-c) post.

And the `*` is for suppressing. ie, the values are just discarded. This additional `scanf()` is done to get the sizes of the strings.

But this is specific to this input.

Comment: Why downvoting?

Comment: @cid  NMDV, yet `100` is arbitrarily and insufficient for OP's `char mystring[1024]`.  The `"%99s"` will stop on white-space unlike OP's unclear `strtok(NULL, s);`.

Comment: @chux What do you mean by NMVD ? Non Minimal Verified something?

Comment: @cid "NMDV" --> not my down vote - I am attempting to provide some rational to another's down vote.