# Updating a matrix with special cases

Tags: c

I am trying to write a function which gets a matrix `9x9` and updates it accordingly to user's input with the following rules:

1. Valid number is between 1 and 9 (zero is invalid).
2. I have to use `scanf` until I get `EOF`.
3. Input has digits and symbols. valid input is a pair of two digits following with a symbol or `EOF` or space. string with more than two digits is invalid. for example (`123%` isn't valid but `12%` is valid).

Example:

Input: `10 33%55^21 $123%`

Output:

```
0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0
0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

Explanation: `10` and `123` are invalid. `33`, `55` and `21` are valid so we will put `1` in `22`, `44` and `10`.

What I tried to do:

```
void updateMarix(int matrix[][9]) {
    int digits = 0, one_previous, two_previous;
    char input;
    while (scanf("%c", &input) != EOF) {
        if(isValidDigit(input)) {
            digits++;
            if(digits == 1) {
                two_previous = input - '0' - 1;
                continue;
            } else if(digits == 2){
                one_previous = input - '0' -1;
                continue;
            }
        } else if(digits == 2) {
            matrix[two_previous][one_previous]++;
        }
        digits = 0; // reset
    }
}
```

most tests are end with success, but some of them are fail. I think that is because I don't handle with the last input (if for example it ends with `22` it won't update it because with my implementation, the update is in the next iteration when other symbol got as input).

Is there a better implementation for this? My code became messy and not clean.

*Edit: It should ignore invalid input and `a3b` doesn't counts, `a03b` also doesn't counts but `a13b` does counts as `13` meaning we should increase the number in `matrix[0][2]`.

Edit 2: @JonathanLeffler  menationed FSM so I tried to create one:

[image]

Although it doesn't handles the case of `1234` (invalid number) or `123` (also invalid). The most similar thing was to create an arrow from `second number` to `symbol` (but it isn't quite true because in `1234%12` only `12` is valid.

Comment: Presumably, a single digit such as `a3b` is invalid too.  I'd be tempted to use a small finite state machine (FSM) and `getchar()` rather than `scanf()` — but `scanf()` does work when used as shown, though I'm not sure if you know why and the limits of what you could vary and still be OK.  An FSM would handle it all straight-forwardly.  You'd have to ensure the end state (moved to on EOF) deals with 2 accumulated digits, though that would only be a problem if the input ended without a newline (or other non-digit) after the last double-digit input. Should it ignore invalid input or identify it?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for your reply. I updated my question. Please take a look.

Answer (score 1):

I think your FSM needs 4 states plus the end state:

1. Zero digits read (D0).
2. One digit read (D1).
3. Two digits read (D2).
4. Digits are invalid but no more error reporting needed (DI).

There are 4 different inputs, too:

1. Digit 1-9.
2. Digit 0.
3. Other.
4. EOF.

I've used a switch on state and if/else code in each state, but it leads to somewhat verbose code.  OTOH, I believe it handles inputs correctly.

```
/*
** FSM
** States: 0 digits (D0), 1 digit (D1), 2 digits (D2), digits invalid (DI)
** Inputs: digit 1-9 (D), digit 0 (0), other (O), EOF.
** Action: S - save, E - error, I - ignore, P - print
** Body of FSM encodes "action;state"
**
** State    D0      D1      D2      DI
** Input
**     D    S;D1    S;D2    E;D2    I;DI
**     O    I;D0    E;D0    P;D0    I;D0
**     0    E;D2    E;D2    E;D2    I;DI
**   EOF    I;end   E;end   P;end   I;end
*/

#include <assert.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

enum State { D0, D1, D2, DI };
enum Input { Digit, Zero, Other, End };

static int debug = 0;

static enum Input input(int *rv)
{
    int c = getchar();
    if (debug)
        printf("Input: %c\n", (c == EOF) ? 'X' : c);
    *rv = c;
    if (c == EOF)
        return End;
    if (isdigit(c))
    {
        *rv = c - '0';
        return (c == '0') ? Zero : Digit;
    }
    return Other;
}

static void updateMatrix(int matrix[9][9])
{
    char pair[2] = { 0, 0 };
    enum State state = D0;

    int c;
    enum Input value;
    while ((value = input(&c)) != End)
    {
        switch (state)
        {
        case D0:
            if (value == Digit)
            {
                pair[0] = c;
                state = D1;
            }
            else if (value == Zero)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Received zero digit - invalid\n");
                state = DI;
            }
            else
            {
                assert(value == Other);
            }
            break;

        case D1:
            if (value == Digit)
            {
                pair[1] = c;
                state = D2;
            }
            else if (value == Zero)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Received zero digit - invalid\n");
                state = DI;
            }
            else
            {
                assert(value == Other);
                fprintf(stderr, "Received one digit where two expected\n");
                state = D0;
            }
            break;

        case D2:
            if (value == Digit)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Received more than two digits where two were expected\n");
                state = DI;
            }
            else if (value == Zero)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Received zero digit - invalid\n");
                state = DI;
            }
            else
            {
                assert(value == Other);
                printf("Valid number %d%d\n", pair[0], pair[1]);
                matrix[pair[0]-1][pair[1]-1] = 1;
                state = D0;
            }
            break;

        case DI:
            if (value == Other)
                state = D0;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (state == D2)
    {
        printf("Valid number %d%d\n", pair[0], pair[1]);
        matrix[pair[0]-1][pair[1]-1] = 1;
    }
    else if (state == D1)
        fprintf(stderr, "Received one digit where two expected\n");
}

static void dump_matrix(const char *tag, int matrix[9][9])
{
    printf("%s:\n", tag);
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
            printf("%4d", matrix[i][j]);
        putchar('\n');
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int matrix[9][9] = { 0 };

    updateMatrix(matrix);
    dump_matrix("After input", matrix);

    return 0;
}
```

On your test input, it produces the output:

```
Received zero digit - invalid
Valid number 33
Valid number 55
Valid number 21
Received more than two digits where two were expected
After input:
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

On the mostly-invalid input file:

```
123345132
bbbb12cccc1dddd011dd
```

it produces the output:

```
Received more than two digits where two were expected
Valid number 12
Received one digit where two expected
Received zero digit - invalid
After input:
   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

You can argue (easily) that the error messages could be more informative (identifying the erroneous character, and possibly the prior valid digits), but it only produces one error message for each invalid sequence, which is beneficial.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it's a very good solution. although my function is a part of an existing code. So I'm trying to find a fix to my function. The FSM was just a method to try to explain what my function needs to do.

Comment: Apart from the spelling fix, I've presented an alternative implementation of your function — a drop-in replacement.  You can remove the `static` of course.  The `input()` function would remain `static`; it's an internal detail.  The dump and main functions are pure test artefacts, of course.  You can proceed with hacking your code if you prefer; it will be hard to make it work smoothly unless you do something analogous to an FSM.  You can also decide you don't care about the printing; that's fine.  It is mostly there to ensure that the FSM works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of `fgets()`, `sscanf()` and `strpbrk()` for this.

The input line is read into a character array `str` and a pointer `ptr` pointing to the part of the string in `str` being processed is maintained.

First, set up a loop to read input line by line. `fgets()` will return `NULL` on `EOF`.

```
for(; fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin); )
{
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

`fgets()` will read in the trailing newline as well. You could remove it like

```
str[strlen(str)-1]='\0';
```

Now inside the above loop, use another loop to process the input line in `str` like

```
    for(ptr=str; (ptr=strpbrk(ptr, "0123456789"))!=NULL; ptr+=len)
    {
        sscanf(ptr, "%d%n", &n, &len);

        if(n>10 && n<100)
        {
             //accepted
             printf("\n%d", n);
             arr[n/10][n%10]=1;
        }
        //else discarded
    }
```

[`strpbrk()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strpbrk)'s prototype is

```
char *strpbrk(const char *s1, const char *s2);
```

and it returns a pointer to the first character in `s1` which is a character in the string `s2`. If there is no match, `NULL` is returned.

So we are looking to see the first digit part in `str` that remains to be processed with `strpbrk(ptr, "0123456789")`.

This number part is read into `n` via `sscanf()`. If this number is in the range you need, you may accept it.

The `%n` format specifier is used to find out the number of characters which has been scanned with the `sscanf()` inorder to find the value by which `ptr` must be updated. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3401156/5375464) post.

The digit in the ones place will be `n%10` and that in the tens place will be `n/10` as the number you need is a 2-digit number.

You may set your array representing the matrix like

```
arr[n/10][n%10]=1;
```

So the whole thing could look something like

```
char *ptr, str[50];
for(; fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin); )
{
    for(ptr=str, str[strlen(str)-1]=0; (ptr=strpbrk(ptr, "0123456789"))!=NULL; ptr+=len)
    {
        sscanf(ptr, "%d%n", &n, &len);
        if(n>10 && n<100)
        {
             printf("\n%d", n);
             arr[n/10][n%10]=1;
        }
    }
}
```

And for your input `10 33%55^21 $123%`, the output would be

```
33
55
21
```

as `10` and `123` will be discarded.