# why use of %n in printf() is not printing the number of variable occurrence before %n In C?

Tags: c, printf, conversion-specifier

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{ 
   int c;
   printf ("the value of %nc :  
   ", &c);

   return 0;
}
```

Output : the value of 0

Comment: Disclaimer: I did not wrap the line.

Comment: If I remove the newline inside quotes, I don't get that output. I get: `the value of c :` (which is what I expected).

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401156/what-is-the-use-of-the-n-format-specifier-in-c) to know what `%n` does.

Comment: `why use of %n in printf() is not printing the number of variable occurrence before %n In C?` because you never printed the collected value!

Answer (score 4):

Per C 2018 7.21.6.1 8, for the conversion specifier `n`:

> The argument shall be a pointer to signed integer into which is *written* the number of characters written to the output stream so far by this call to `fprintf` [or `printf`].…

Thus, the effect of `printf ("the value of %nc :  ", &c);` is to write the characters “the value of c :  ” to output and to put the number of characters in “the value of ” in `c`, which is 13.

Comment: Any idea why OP has that output? They never printed any integer value, so how can there be a `0`?

Comment: @SouravGhosh: Inaccurate reporting of source code or results.

Answer (score 2):

For starters you may not split a string literal with an intermediate new line character. So this call

```
   printf ("the value of %nc :  
   ", &c);
```

is syntactically invalid. Either write

```
   printf ("the value of %nc :  \n   ", &c);
```

or write

```
       printf ("the value of %nc :  \n"
   "", &c);
```

In the call above the function `printf` does not output the value of the variable `c` itself. You need an additional call of the function `printf` to output the value of the variable `c`.

If you want to do this in one line then you can write as it is seen in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
   int c;

   printf( "%d\n",  ( printf ("the value of %nc :  ",  &c ), c ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
the value of c :  13
```

Or if you want to include a new line character in the outputted string literal you can rewrite the call pf `printf` the following way

```
printf( "%d\n",  ( printf ("the value of %nc :  \n   ",  &c ), c ) );
```

In this case the program output will look like

```
the value of c :  
   13
```

Comment: Those two first fixed `printf` seem wrong, they don't produce the newline (which I presume is askers intention).

Comment: @hyde If the new line character is required I included it.:)