# Insert integer in middle of pointer string in C

Tags: c, string, pointers

I have a string named pos, and I want to insert integer in middle of string. I am new to C.

My code is

```
char *pos;
int i = 1;

pos = "(%d)",i;
printf("%s",pos);
```

I get this output `(%d)`

Whereas I want `(1)`

Correct me if my approach is wrong.

**I know I can directly print it but I want to use the variable in program.**

Edit: I have switched from C++, I haven't read much about pointers till yet

The function definition is defined in `int program_list(char *programs[],int program_len,int progress[],int progress_len)`

by the way my entire program is

```
#include <stdlib.h> // exit()
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h> // clrscr(), getch()

#define width 68
#define array_size(arr) ((sizeof(arr))/(sizeof(*arr)))

void ln();
int program_list(char *programs[],int program_len,int progress[],int progress_len);
void get_elements(int arr[],int size);
void display_elements(int arr[],int size);
int insert_element(int arr[],int *size,int pos,int item);
int delete_element(int arr[],int *size,int pos);
int linear_search(int arr[],int beg,int last,int item);
int binary_search(int arr[],int beg,int last,int item);
void swap(int *a,int *b);
int bubble_sort(int arr[],int size);

int main() {
    int item,opt,size,pos,arr[20];
    int progress[] = {6,7,11,14,15,16};
    char *programs[] = {"GCD of 2 nos. using recursion",
                      "Fibonacci series using recursion",
                      "Length of string, concatenate 2 strings using pointer",
                      "Copy a string, extract substring from string using pointers",
                      "Tower of Hanoi with 3 discs using recursion",
                      "Insert integer in array",
                      "Delete integer from array",
                      "Create linked list and display it",
                      "Sort N nos. using insertion sort",
                      "Sort N nos. using selection sort",
                      "Sort N nos. using bubble sort",
                      "Sort N nos. using merge sort",
                      "Sort N nos. using quick sort",
                      "Binary Search using recursion",
                      "Linear Search using recursion",
                      "EXIT"
                     };

    do{
    
       opt = program_list(programs,array_size(programs),progress,array_size(progress));
       
       switch(opt){

          case 1:
             break;

          case 2:
             break;

          case 3:
             break;

          case 4:
             break;

          case 5:
             break;

          case 6:
             printf("\nEnter size of array : ");
             scanf("%d",&size);
             printf("Enter elements of array -:");
             get_elements(arr,size);
             printf("Elements of array -:");
             display_elements(arr,size);
             printf("At which index you want to insert? : ");
             scanf("%d",&pos);
             printf("Enter value which you want to insert : ");
             scanf("%d",&item);
             
             *arr = insert_element(arr,&size,pos,item);
             
             printf("Elements of array after insertion -:");
             display_elements(arr,size);
             
             break;

          case 7:
             printf("\nEnter size of array : ");
             scanf("%d",&size);
             printf("Enter elements of array -:");
             get_elements(arr,size);
             printf("Elements of array -:");
             display_elements(arr,size);
             printf("Enter index which you want to delete : ");
             scanf("%d",&pos);

             *arr = delete_element(arr,&size,pos);

             printf("Elements of array after deletion -:");
             display_elements(arr,size);
             
             break;

          case 8:
             break;

          case 9:
             break;

          case 10:
             break;
             
          case 11:
             printf("\nEnter size of array : ");
             scanf("%d",&size);
             printf("Enter elements of array -:");
             get_elements(arr,size);
             printf("Elements of array -:");
             display_elements(arr,size);
             
             *arr = bubble_sort(arr,size);
             
             printf("Sorted array using bubble sort -:");
             display_elements(arr,size);
             
             break;
             
          case 12:
             break;
             
          case 13:
             break;
             
          case 14:
             printf("\nEnter size of array : ");
             scanf("%d",&size);
             printf("Enter elements of array -:");
             get_elements(arr,size);
             printf("Elements of array -:");
             display_elements(arr,size);
             printf("Enter value which you want to search : ");
             scanf("%d",&item);
             
             pos = binary_search(arr,0,size-1,item);
             if(pos==-1){
                printf("%d not found using binary search\n",item);
             }
             else{
                printf("arr[%d] = %d (found using binary search)\n",pos,item);
             }
             
             break;
             
          case 15:
             printf("\nEnter size of array : ");
             scanf("%d",&size);
             printf("Enter elements of array -:");
             get_elements(arr,size);
             printf("Elements of array -:");
             display_elements(arr,size);
             printf("Enter value which you want to search : ");
             scanf("%d",&item);
             
             pos = linear_search(arr,0,size-1,item);
             if(pos==-1){
                printf("%d not found using linear search\n",item);
             }
             else{
                printf("arr[%d] = %d (found using linear search)\n",pos,item);
             }

             break;

          case 16:
             exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
             break;

          default:
             printf("Enter valid choice!\n");
             opt=0;

       }
       
       printf("Program finished! Press enter to restart");
       getch(); // use getch() two times for linux based OS (modified by me)
       getch();
       

    }while( opt>=0 && opt<=array_size(programs) );

    return 0;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void ln(){
   printf("\n");
} // function to leave a line


int program_list(char *programs[],int program_len,int progress[],int progress_len){
   clrscr();
   int opt,i=0,j,k;
   char *text,*status,*pos;
   
   while(i>=0 && i<=2){
      switch(i){
      case 1:
         for(j=0;j<program_len;j++){
            for(k=0;k<=width;k++){
               if(k==0 || k==width) printf("|");
               else{
                  if(linear_search(progress,0,progress_len,j+1)==-1) status="  ";
                  else status="->";
                  pos = "(%d) ",(j+1);
                  text = programs[j];
                  printf("%s%s%s",status,pos,text);
                  k=strlen(status)+strlen(pos)+strlen(text);
                  while(k<width-1){
                     printf(" ");
                     k++;
                  }
               }
            }
            ln();
         }
         break;
      default:
         for(j=0;j<=width;j++){
            if(j==0 || j==width) printf("+");
            else printf("-");
         }
         ln();
      }
      i++;
   }
   printf("\nYour option : ");
   scanf("%d",&opt);
   return opt;
} // function to display list of programs in beautiful manner


void get_elements(int arr[],int size){
   int i;
   ln();
   for(i=0;i<size;i++){
      printf("arr[%d] -> ",i);
      scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
   }
   ln();
} // function to get elements in array


void display_elements(int arr[],int size){
   int i;
   ln();
   for(i=0;i<size;i++){
      printf("arr[%d] = %d\n",i,arr[i]);
   }
   ln();
} // function to display elements of array


int insert_element(int arr[],int *size,int pos,int item){
   if (pos>*size){
      printf("OVERFLOW\n");
   }
   else{
      int i;
      for(i=*size;i>pos;i--){
         arr[i]=arr[i-1];
      }
      arr[pos] = item;
      *size = *size+1;
   }
   return *arr;
} // function to insert element in array


int delete_element(int arr[],int *size,int pos){
   if (pos>*size){
      printf("OVERFLOW\n");
   }
   else{
      *size = *size-1;
      int i;
      for(i=pos;i<*size;i++){
         arr[i]=arr[i+1];
      }
   }
   return *arr;
} // function to delete element from array


int linear_search(int arr[],int beg,int last,int item){
   if (beg<=last){
      if(arr[beg]==item){
         return beg;
      }
      return linear_search(arr,beg+1,last,item);
   }
   return -1;
} // function to search elements using linear search


int binary_search(int arr[],int beg,int last,int item){
   if (beg<=last){
      int mid;
      mid = (beg+last)/2;
      if(arr[mid]==item){
         return mid;
      }
      if(arr[mid]>item){
         return binary_search(arr,beg,mid-1,item);
      }
      return binary_search(arr,mid+1,last,item);
   }
   return -1;
} // function to search elements using binary search


void swap(int *a,int *b){
   int temp;
   temp = *a;
   *a = *b;
   *b = temp;
} // function to swap numbers


int bubble_sort(int arr[],int size){
   int i=0,j;
   while(i<size-1){
      j=0;
      while(j<size-1-i){
         if(arr[j]>arr[j+1]){
            swap(&arr[j],&arr[j+1]);
         }
         j++;
      }
      i++;
   }
   return *arr;
} // function to sort array using bubble sorting

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

My output
[image]

Comment: Have you made any attempt to learn the language properly by reading a C book or tutorial? Or do any basic research by searching for examples on how to do what you want?

Comment: @kaylum Sorry, I havent't researched more about C

Comment: There's no built-in operation to insert in the middle of a C string. You need to put the result in a new string.

Comment: @Barmar Therefore, I need a function or algorithm which can make the job done

Comment: Arrays and `snprintf`? (`char pos[16]; snprintf(pos, sizeof pos, "(%d)", i);`)

Comment: You say you want to insert into the middle of a string, but it looks like you just want to use the string as a `printf` format. `printf(pos, i)` should do what you want.

Comment: Shall I remove my question if it is misleading??

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I don't know the position, because its dynamic( I don't know if I am using correct terminologies )

Comment: @Barmar Sorry, I am not able to understand, would you please like to correct my output screen? I have attached a picture of output

Comment: If your program which constructs the format strings internally through code, it could instead insert data as and when needed instead of constructing format string. If the format strings are input from a user, then you should stop that immediately as that opens up your program for all kinds of abuses and security holes.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I understand your answer now! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `pos` variable. Just put what you want in the `printf()` format string.

To get the length that was printed, use the `%n` format specifier rather than adding `strlen()`. See [What is the use of the %n format specifier in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401156/what-is-the-use-of-the-n-format-specifier-in-c)

```
for(j=0;j<program_len;j++){
    for(k=0;k<=width;k++){
        if(k==0 || k==width) printf("|");
        else{
            if(linear_search(progress,0,progress_len,j+1)==-1) status="  ";
            else status="->";
            text = programs[j];
            printf("%s(%d)%s%n",status,j+1,text, &k);
            while(k<width-1){
                printf(" ");
                k++;
            }
        }
    }
    ln();
}
```

But if you really want another variable, declare it as an array, not a pointer. Then use `sprintf()` to format it.

```
for(j=0;j<program_len;j++){
    for(k=0;k<=width;k++){
        if(k==0 || k==width) printf("|");
        else{
            if(linear_search(progress,0,progress_len,j+1)==-1) status="  ";
            else status="->";
            text = programs[j];
            char pos[20];
            sprintf(pos, "(%d)", i+1);
            printf("%s%s%s%n",status,pos,text, &k);
            while(k<width-1){
                printf(" ");
                k++;
            }
        }
    }
    ln();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Using an array, the sprintf worked for me

Comment: The second code worked instead of first because I need to include the space it takes, otherwise  ` | `  this would not occur at proper position

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to do that without the `pos` variable.

Comment: Thanks for giving your time for solving my problem, I understood I can directly print but I need to consider the length so that it could fit with appropriate spaces, anyway thanks!

Comment: I understand that. `%n` gets the length and puts it in `k`.

Comment: OH! sorry i didn't pay attention to that !! It worked. I learned something new today